# Springboot Dynamic JSON content fetch through filter

Tags: spring-boot, servlet-filters

I have json data asset in my Springboot powered web-app as follows

> webapp/asset/labels.json
>
> webapp/asset/dept1/labels.json
>
> webapp/asset/dept2/labels.json

From the UI layer, a REST call occurs to fetch the labels (http://server/asset/labels.json). Now I want to dynamically fetch the contents of the labels json overwritten 
with /dept1/labels.json-if the person belongs to dept1, 
with /dept2/labels.json-if the person belongs to dept2.

labels.json

```
{"Foo" : "1","Bar" : "X"}
```

dept1/labels.json

```
{"Foo" : "2"}
```

dept2/labels.json

```
{"Bar" : "Y"}
```

**Expected Json content expected by front-end when /asset/labels.json is invoked**

For Employee who doesn't belong to Dept1 or Dept2

```
{"Foo" : "1","Bar" : "X"}
```

For Employee who belong to Dept1

```
{"Foo" : "2","Bar" : "X"}
```

For Employee who belong to Dept2

```
{"Foo" : "1","Bar" : "Y"}
```

I tried various approaches but in most cases I ended up custom implementation for each API. I have hundreds of json to handle, so I am wondering if there is a way to come up with a custom framework/utility which can handle for all JSON files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have an API endpoint which will return the correct JSON.

In the API endpoint method you would follow the below steps:

- First load the base JSON file into a `Map` say `baseMap`.
- Next based on the user's dept you load the dept specific JSON into another Map say `deptMap`
- then you run this line of code: `baseMap.putAll(deptMap)`

The `putAll` will override any keys coming from department specific JSON.

**Note**:

There will be only ONE end point and this end point will determine Employee either based on the employee name passed to it as query parameter or obtains it based on the logged in user

Comment: currently there is no backend implementation, the json asset is directly invoked by UI layer using the URL. If I go with the above approach, I may have to implement hundreds of end points (one for each json) and implement the logic.

Comment: You will not have hundreds of endpoints. If you read and understood my answer correctly - there will be only 1 end point